# No viable conversion from std::function to bool

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

The C++11 `std::function` is supposed to implement [`operator bool() const`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/operator_bool/), so why does clang tell me there is no viable conversion?

```
#include <functional>
#include <cstdio>

inline double the_answer() 
    { return 42.0; }

int main()
{
    std::function<double()> f;

    bool yes = (f = the_answer);

    if (yes) printf("The answer is %.2f\n",f());
}
```

The compiling error is:

```
function_bool.cpp:12:7: error: no viable conversion from 'std::function<double ()>' to 'bool'
        bool yes = (f = the_answer);
             ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

**EDIT** I didn't see the `explicit` keyword.. no implicit conversion then, I guess I'll have to use `static_cast`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Call function?

Comment: You can answer it if you want. Note that `f = the_answer; if (f) {...}` also works.

Comment: Linked Duplicate: [Why std::function does not implicitly convert to bool in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39590272/514235)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`operator bool()` for `std::function` is `explicit`, therefore it cannot be used for copy-initialization. You can actually do direct-initialization:

```
bool yes(f = the_answer);
```

However, I assume it's really intended for *contextual conversion*, which happens when an expression is used as a condition, most often for an `if` statement. Contextual conversion can call `explicit` constructors and conversion functions, unlike implicit conversion.

```
// this is fine (although compiler might warn)
if (f = the_answer) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Cheers, I wanted to use implicit conversion in methods like `bool Foo::check() const { return m_function; }`. Too bad for me :)

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: you can write that as `bool Foo::check() const { return m_function ? true : false; }` if you really want to avoid explicit casts.

Comment: @ChrisDodd `return !!m_function;`.