# Why std::function does not implicitly convert to bool in C++11?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, implicit-conversion, std-function

Consider the following code.

```
#include <functional>

int main(void)
{
    std::function<void()> f1;
    if (f1) { /* ok */
        ...
    }

    bool b = f1; /* compile-error */
    bool B = !f1; /* ok */
    ...
}
```

`std::function<>` converts implicitly to bool in some circumstances but not in all of them. Assigning it to a `bool`-variable does not work, whereas the result of an operation or using it in an `if()`-statement is OK.

Why is that so? It seems we have to do an boolean-operation on it, then the conversion works.

What I did to make work the `b = f1`-line is the good ol' double bang: `!!`. It looks like an antique in such modern C++-code.

*EDIT*: This compiles as well:

```
bool b = f1 || f1; /* OK */
```

Comment: Because the operator bool is marked as explicit. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool

Comment: @wasthishelpful It is the same answer, but not the same question. IMHO

Comment: Our answer here is better.

Comment: Note that `bool b{f1};` and `bool b(f1);` both work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that [std::function::operator bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool) is `explicit` conversion function, implicit conversion is not allowed. So `bool b = f1;` won't work. (Explicit conversion will work well if you use  [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) like `bool b = static_cast<bool>(f1);`.)

> using it in an `if()`-statement is OK.

When being used with `if`, `operator!` or `operator||`, [contextual conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions) will take effect, and the explicit conversion function will be considered.

(since C++11)

> In the following five contexts, the type `bool` is expected and the implicit conversion sequence is built if the declaration `bool t(e);` is well-formed. that is, the explicit user-defined conversion function such as `explicit T::operator bool() const;` is considered. Such expression e is said to be *contextually convertible to bool*.
>
> - controlling expression of `if`, `while`, `for`;
> - the logical operators `!`, `&&` and `||`;
> - the conditional operator `?:`;
> - `static_assert`;
> - `noexcept`.

Comment: So there are implicit, explicit and contextually implicit conversions even if explicit is requested. Good to know.

Comment: @PatrickB. Because of the `!` the `bool` conversion is still applied implicitly even though it was declared `explicit`.

Comment: So would !!f1 work for this?

Comment: @Goosebumps Yes, `!f1` will cause `f1` to be converted to `bool`, the converted value is applied for `!` and then the result is applied for `!` again.